# Playwright - TypeError: hoverElement.hover is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright

I am trying to run this

```
await hoverElement.hover();
```

so that the mouse will hover over the element in question

I get an error saying TypeError: hoverElement.hover is not a function

I am reading from the playwright API documentation https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.5.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=elementhandlehoveroptions

What am I doing wrong?

```
test('Selection using hover Speak', async () => {

if (EnableTests.run_hover_speak === "true") {

    const expectedResult = TestPage.Div2_Expected_Result;
    const hoverElement = TestPage.Div2_css;

    await test_functions._hoverSpeak(page);
    await hoverElement.hover();

    const highlightedText =  await test_functions._hiliteSelection(page);
    const actual = JSON.stringify(highlightedText); console.log("ACTUAL RESPONSE " + actual);
    const expected = JSON.stringify(expectedResult); console.log("EXPECTED RESPONSE " + expected);
    assert(expected === actual);

};
```

});

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of your code?

Comment: Sounds like hoverElement is not correct

Comment: I've shared more of the code on my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hoverElement.hover` is not a function, then it implies that `hoverElement` (and therefore `TestPage.Div2_css`) is probably not a proper Playwright `elementHandle` object.  I can't see from your code where you get `TestPage` from, but it might be that `Div2_css` is a reference to a plain DOM node, or its CSS, rather than an `elementHandle`.

To fix this, you might need to assign `hoverElement` using something like [`page.$('.div2')`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.5.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=elementhandleselector) (replace `.div2` with a suitable [selector](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.5.2&path=docs%2Fselectors.md&q=) to target the element you want to hover over).